# Fridge and freezer getting warm after power outage but still turns on

Tags: refrigerator, appliances

While asking more generally about what could be wrong with a fridge in general based on the potential cause and symptoms to keep the answer relevant for others, this is in regards to a 2013 GE Cafe model CFCP1RKBDSS if that matters.

The fridge has been working normally for 7 years. Power has gone out a handful of times each year, never caused an issue. We had to turn off the power to the house at the circuit breaker yesterday for a moment. The next morning noticed the refridgerator temperature was very warm. Rather than 0/37 was 42/52 or so and seems to be getting warmer. Everything turns on normally, and can feel cool air blowing but I I assume it's blowing either less powerfully or less cold than normal. Also cold air blowing out the back bottom vent.

Because of the pandemic called 5 local repair shops and all our booked for weeks, and once we get an appointment it could be weeks or longer to get a part presumably. Even buying a new fridge it appears most all the similar fridges are back ordered for months. So hoping to get at least an educated guess on what the issue may be, so we can determine a very rough estimate on if it would potentially be a small part or a major part.

Comment: The first things I'd do are to check the condenser coil (usually under or behind the unit) for blockage or dirt/dust and also check the evaporator coil (inside the unit) for ice.  I'm betting on ice buildup.

Comment: I would check the bottom of the freezer compartment, sometimes when a heavy defrost I have seen the bottom get full and freeze blocking the airflow this prevents a good circulation and with some units the fridge just has a couple of ports from the freezer side for cooling. You said the fan is working that is one issue that can go from working to warm.

Comment: @jwh20 the bottom back right is very dusty. So was wondering if could be that but seemed like if that was the case over the past weeks or months it would have slowly started getting warmer rather than going from normal to everything melting over night following a power outage. But could dirty coil cause this issue all at once?

Comment: To note, the issue effects the fridge and the freezer and nothing blocking in the top refridge part. So could the freezer being blocked affect the fridge area too?

Comment: @cchiera  My rule is that you never rule out a potential cause until you know the true cause.  Try cleaning it and see if that resolves the issue.  Perhaps there was enough capacity to keep it cold but not enough to cool after a warm-up.